# PHP simpleXML Scope

Tags: php, xml, arrays, parsing, xml-parsing

This is my first time using XML documents. What I'm trying to do is extract some information from a spotify search. e.g. this page: [Spotify Results](http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify%3aalbum:77Tgq2oSMvgP4Y9pBVKRJa&extras=trackdetail)

I'm not that good with scoping, everything I know so far has been from tutorials.

What I want the end results to look like is somthing like this:

```
(Album Name) - (Artist Name) (year)

(track number) - (Track Name) - (length)
(track number) - (Track Name) - (length)
(track number) - (Track Name) - (length)
...
```

Here is the code I have so far.

```
<?php
 function print_r2($val){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($val);
        echo  '</pre>';
}

$URL = "http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify:album:77Tgq2oSMvgP4Y9pBVKRJa&extras=trackdetail";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($URL) 
   or die("Error: Cannot create object");

//print_r2($xml);

foreach($xml->children() as $album){
    echo($album->name);
    echo($album->artist->name);
    echo($album->released);

    foreach($album->children() as $track => $data){
      echo $data->{'track-number'};
      echo("  -  ");
      echo $data->name;
      echo("  -  ");
      echo $data->length;
      echo "<br />";
    }
}

?>
```

The Problem that I'm having is the Artist Name and Year is not showing, and also it's putting in more " - " then there needs to be. (guessing it has something to do with children() but not outputting any data.)

Also, I was thinking about having this information saved into an array and processing that data into a SQL database. If you know of a better way of writing it with the array that would be awesome. (kill two birds with one stone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Super simple way to parse XML to a workable array is like so:

```
<?php 
$xml = file_get_contents('http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify:album:77Tgq2oSMvgP4Y9pBVKRJa&extras=trackdetail');

//Type cast XML into Array
$a = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($xml)),1);

//See the full array
//print_r($a);

echo $a['name'].' - '.$a['artist']['name'].' - '.$a['released'].'<br />'.PHP_EOL;

foreach($a['tracks']['track'] as $track){
    echo $track['track-number'].' - '.$track['name'].' - '.secondsToTime($track['length']).'<br />'.PHP_EOL;
}

/*
Be Lifted High - Bethel Live - 2011<br />
1 - You Are Good (feat. Brian Johnson) - 4m25s<br />
2 - One Thing Remains (feat. Brian Johnson) - 5m0s<br />
3 - Furious (feat. Jeremy Riddle) - 5m16s<br />
4 - Be Lifted High (feat. Brian Johnson) - 6m54s<br />
5 - God I Look To You (feat. Jenn Johnson) - 7m32s<br />
6 - I Will Exalt (feat. Amanda Falk) - 6m44s<br />
7 - What Would I Have Done (feat. Brian Johnson and Jenn Johnson) - 6m13s<br />
8 - Hope's Anthem (feat. William Matthews) - 5m45s<br />
9 - Love Came Down (feat. Brian Johnson) - 5m6s<br />
10 - Deep Cries Out (feat. William Matthews) - 5m14s<br />
11 - God Of The Redeemed (feat. Jeremy Riddle) - 6m8s<br />
12 - Forever And A Day (feat. Jenn Johnson) - 7m5s<br />
13 - One Thirst (feat. Jeremy Riddle and Steffany Frizzell) - 7m5s<br />
*/

function secondsToTime($seconds){
     // minutes
    $divisor_for_minutes = $seconds % (60 * 60);
    $minutes = floor($divisor_for_minutes / 60);

    // seconds
    $divisor_for_seconds = $divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    $seconds = ceil($divisor_for_seconds);

    // return the final song len string
    return $minutes."m".$seconds."s";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! that really helped. While I was waiting for a reply I played around with the time and came up with this    echo (gmdate("H:i:s", round(floatval($data->length)))); but I will save the function for a later date, I'm sure i'm going to needed it sometime.

Answer (score 2):

The root node is "album".   You are referencing `$root->children()`, when you should just treat the root node as an album object.

```
$url = "http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify:album:77Tgq2oSMvgP4Y9pBVKRJa&extras=trackdetail";

$album = simplexml_load_file($url)
    or die("Error: Cannot create object");

echo("name: " . $album->name . "\n");
echo("artist: " . $album->artist->name . "\n");
echo("released: " . $album->released . "\n");
echo "Tracks:\n" ;
foreach($album->tracks->children() as $track){
    echo "  " . $track->{'track-number'} .
        "  -  " .
            $track->name .
            "  -  " .
            $track->length .
            "<br />\n";
}
```

output:

```
name: Be Lifted High
artist: Bethel Live
released: 2011
Tracks:
1  -  You Are Good (feat. Brian Johnson)  -  265.520000<br />
2  -  One Thing Remains (feat. Brian Johnson)  -  300.973000<br />
3  -  Furious (feat. Jeremy Riddle)  -  316.440000<br />
4  -  Be Lifted High (feat. Brian Johnson)  -  414.493000<br />
5  -  God I Look To You (feat. Jenn Johnson)  -  452.520000<br />
6  -  I Will Exalt (feat. Amanda Falk)  -  404.880000<br />
7  -  What Would I Have Done (feat. Brian Johnson and Jenn Johnson)  -  373.160000<br />
8  -  Hope's Anthem (feat. William Matthews)  -  345.160000<br />
9  -  Love Came Down (feat. Brian Johnson)  -  306.880000<br />
10  -  Deep Cries Out (feat. William Matthews)  -  314.480000<br />
11  -  God Of The Redeemed (feat. Jeremy Riddle)  -  368.426000<br />
12  -  Forever And A Day (feat. Jenn Johnson)  -  425.466000<br />
13  -  One Thirst (feat. Jeremy Riddle and Steffany Frizzell)  -  425.493000<br />
```

Comment: Awesome, Really helped me understand the scoping with the way your wrote your foreach and above.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you:

```
<?php
$url = "http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify:album:77Tgq2oSMvgP4Y9pBVKRJa&extras=trackdetail";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($url));

$album = array(
    'name' => (string) $xml->name,
    'artist' => (string) $xml->artist->name,
    'released' => (string) $xml->released,
    'tracks' => array()
);

foreach ($xml->tracks->track as $track) {
    $album['tracks'][] = array(
        'number' => (string) $track->{'track-number'},
        'name' => (string) $track->name,
        'length' => (string) $track->length
    );
}

print_r($album);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about going with a two dimensional array, but wasn't sure how to do it properly. Might play around with Lawrence's and your code and see what works the best for my application.